# Assembly dependent extension of classes

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I'm splitting my code (c#.net 4.5) into several assemblies. The reason is that I program several applications that reuse different sets of code.

I want to extend functionality from assembly 2 to assembly 1 - without referencing from 1 to 2.

But I only want the extension to happen when the executing assembly is another assembly (3) that reference both assembly 1 and 2.

Just like extension methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx - but with the option to extend objects with real fields.

How?

I have made a case. Example of what I want....

```
// Assembly 1
// no references to other assemblies

class ObjA
{
    ObjA() 
    {

    }
}

// Assembly 2
// reference to assembly 1

class ObjA
{

    ObjA()
    {

    }

    void SaveNow()
    {
       // save
    }

}

// Assembly 3
// reference to assembly 1 and 2

class ObjA
{
    ObjA()
    {

    }
}

static void SomeWhereInMyCode(ObjA x)
{
    x.SaveNow(); // should be visible
}
```

I realise that you can't extend (like partial class) objects across asseblies like I did above. Therefore I have made this solution...

```
// Assembly1
// no references to other assemblies

class ObjA
{

    ObjBInterface objBInterface;

    ObjA() 
    {

    }

}

interface ObjBInterface
{
    void Save();
}

// Assembly 2
// reference to assembly 1

class ObjBClass : ObjBInterface
{
    public void SaveNow()
    {
       // save
    }
}

// Assembly 3
// reference to assembly 1 and 2

static void SomeWhereInMyCode(ObjA a)
{

    ObjBInterface b = a.objBInterface;

    if(b != null)
    {
        ObjBClass b2 = (ObjBClass)b;
        b2.SaveNow();
    }    
}
```

This works but its not optimal. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Having names like `MyWorkerObject` I find it hard to figure out what you're trying to do. Can you describe what `MyWorkerObject` represents?

Comment: I dosn't really matter what the base object do. In my real project all custom objs derive from from it. There are many custom objects that do different stuff: Friend, Song, File, User, ClientAttached, CustomStream objects etc. All these objs have different functionality in common. That functionality kept in the base class. This functionality include:
- unique ids
- variables, like creationtime
- relations to other custom objects and base objects
- relation to collections
- relations to client object actually using the object live
- init and dispose functionality
- etc

Comment: What is your concrete problem?

Comment: My problem is that in a given assembly I want to extend functionality of my base object - depending on what other assemblies my given assembly is dependent on. F.ex. if the given assembly is dependent upon 'assembly that handles db'. my base object should automatically extend when constructed to include db functionality and fields. Just like a partial class (i know that only works on one assembly).

Comment: IMHO this sounds like you need to review how you are designing your classes. Maybe you should put the saving logic in an external class that would be where it is pertinent to be (assembly 2 in this case I believe).

Comment: @Crono1981. Thx. I see your point. Thats actually what I've done in 'Example of what I have done now' above. Then the case class exist in one assembly (#1) and the saving logic seperate object exist in another assembly (#2) with reference from #2 > #1. Problem is then the main class cannot call f.ex. save. You might be wondering: Why does he not just reference from #1 > #2. But I have other assemblies (serperate applications) that only need a reference to assembly #1 (they are non-db). I'm looking for like: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx but with extension of real objects.

Comment: No, I mean a whole other class, not a derived. A class that is made to save objects of type "MyWorkerObject".

Comment: Right. I edited the post to make it more understandable, sorry I'm not good at explaing myself. In the second code area you can see that the 'save object' is in fact a whole other class: "ObjBClass". Its just inherited from an interface located in assembly 1 to make it possible to call it from assembly one whitout a reference from assembly 1 > 2. So it will be called when time for a save and if not null (the 3rd assembly will make sure its not null, as also the only assembly with reference to both 1 and 2).

Comment: ObjA should not know anything about ObjB or ObjBInterface. It shouldn't be able to access a property path allowing it to save itself. Its sole responsibility should be holding your data together, nothing more. In other terms: ObjB and/or ObjBInterface may know about ObjA, but not the other way around.

Comment: Take ADO.NET, for example: data adapters are aware of datasets, but datasets knows nothing of data adapters. All they do is holding data together.